# How to limit count of ssh port forwarding per user

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, socks5

i want to limit a nologin system user to make one, or two ssh tunnel.

this user use `ssh system-user@server-ip -D 1080 -N` command

need something like `maxlogins` in **limits.conf**

is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You could set in `sshd_config` the setting `MaxSessions` (default 10) but then they could just open another ssh connection to get more, so you'd also have to couple that with setting `maxlogins` in `limits.conf`.

However, `-D` is usually used for SOCKS proxy, which is tied to a web browser, which usually opens multiple streams at once.  Even the default 10 can be a low limit for that, so if you set it to 1 without also changing the web browser's simultaneous connection limit, you are likely to break the web browser using the ssh connection.

Comment: this is a nologin system user so  `maxlogins` in limits.conf is not useful and `MaxSessions` has no effect on port forwarding

Comment: MaxSessions controls port multiplexing, which explicitly includes port forwarding.  I've had to adjust this number up specifically to handle `-D` connections.  When you connect with ssh, it is a login session, although you aren't getting a shell in this case.  I haven't tested if systemd counts it under maxlogins however.

Comment: I just checked.  If you use `loginctl list-sessions` on your remote machine you will find the ssh forwarding sessions are there (without a shell), and you verify that with `loginctl session-status ` followed by each number from list-sessions.   Each of those counts under maxlogins.

Comment: `limits.conf` : `sys_test         -       maxlogins       2`,
`sshd_config` : `MaxSessions 1`,
`loginctl list-sessions` : 
SESSION UID USER     SEAT TTY
    676 998 sys_test         
    679   0 root             
    700 998 sys_test         
    701 998 sys_test         
    702 998 sys_test         

9 sessions listed.

Comment: i set maxlogins 2 and MaxSessions 1, now i test 4 `ssh sys_test@185.216.26.95 -D [1081-1084] -N` and all of them working

Comment: might need to reset services and close existing sessions before the new numbers take effect.